# how to add a "Please select" item to a dropdown box in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox

i have the following code in an asp.net mvc view.

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(Model.Items, "Id", "Name", 0), new { @id = "Filter", @class = "autoComplete1" })%>
```

i want to add an element at the top of the dropdown as the first item that says, "Please select".

do i have to add that into my Model.Items or is there a way i can add that element into the view and ignore the selection of that first element ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do:

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(Model.Items, "Id", "Name", 0), "Please Select", new { @id = "Filter", @class = "autoComplete1" })%>
```

Its a little long to read, but the method signature is:

```
DropDownList(name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, optionLabel, htmlAttributes)
```

Comment: How can I set the value of the "Please Select" list item?

Comment: Nice and clean answer

Comment: While it is indead clean it doesnt show u how to stop it being selected by a user please select should not be able to be selected by a user